# Hive Table add partition to load all subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr, emr

I'm using hive (with external tables) to process data stored on amazon S3.

My data is partitioned as follows:
`group/team/dt/` (e.g., a data file may be stored in a path `group=myGroup/team=myTeam/dt=20120603`)

I would like to process data for several teams (in different groups).
Since RCOVER PARTITIONS takes a long time, I want to add multiple partitions based on group and team values to the hive table (i.e., given a group and team load data for all dates available in that team).

The functionality I'm looking for is:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myData(
attr1 string, attr2 string, attr3 string)
PARTITIONED BY (group string, team string, dt string )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/${DATA_ROOT_DIR}'; 

-- Add paritions without specifying values for dt
ALTER TABLE myData ADD PARTITION (group='group1',team='team1') ; 
ALTER TABLE myData ADD PARTITION (group='group2',team='team2') ;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Hive doesn't know about those directories until you tell it about them, so there's no way to access the partitions without adding them.

You could write a simple script to add all the partitions for a given team/group:

```
results = "ALTER TABLE something ADD "
groups.each do |group|
  teams.each do |team|
    partitions = listDirectories("s3n://bucket/", group, team)
    partitions.each do |partition|
      results += "PARTITION(group='#{group}', team='#{team}', dt='#{partition}')"
    end

  end
end

puts results
```

Looks like you're running on EMR (regular hive doesn't even have RECOVER PARTITIONS), that's pretty much what RECOVER PARTITIONS does anyway, but this way you have more control at least.

The other option is to add the partitions when you add the data, and just make sure all the partitions stay up to date.

Comment: How, or on what do I run this script?

Answer (score 0):

Please check Dynamic-partition Insert - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-DynamicpartitionInsert

in this method, the column itself becomes the partition. This effectively avoids hard-coding the partition name in the insert statement.

Comment: The question is about recovering/adding a partition and not about dynamically creating a partition. According to question, partition already exists, he wants to recover certain partitions selectively.